# Uno Platform - Not found in Visual Studio Extension Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2019, uno-platform

The Extension Manager in Visual Studio 2019 returns nothing when searching for the Uno Platform extension.

Answer (score 2):

The search function in the Extensions manager seems to've changed (for the worse) in the most recent versions of Visual Studio 2019. Now to find the Uno Platform Solution Templates, searching just "uno" won't work. Searching for "uno platform solution" will, however. Searching for "webassembly" will also work.

Hopefully this is a bug in Visual Studio that gets addressed soon.